# Motion Sensor Timer

Tags: lighting, outdoor, timer

I am looking to replace the light switch for an outside light. What I would like to do is put a motion sensor on the switch due to the fact the light is too high for me to get to and replace it. Is there a product that would allow me to just replace the inside switch? A timer switch would also work.

I can't find any type of switch to allow me to achieve this. Do you have any suggestions?

The switch is on the inside, lights on outside.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're asking.  If you replace the switch that controls an outside light with a motion sensor, the light will turn on when it senses motion **inside**.  Is this what you are trying to accomplish, or do you want the light to come on when motion is sensed **outside**? Are both the switch and light outside?

Comment: Where is the light switch now, on the inside or the outside? If outside, is facing the area where the motion you want to detect will occur?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your switch with a **motion activated switch**. You can find them on eBay, Amazon and any electrical shop near you!

[image]

Or you can also use a **timer switch (wall)** also found in the same places.

[image]

As mentioned in comments and also a really cool idea. A wireless motion sensor switch. A bit more difficult to find but they are out there.

[image]

All of these will require some electrical skills. Make sure you **turn off** your mains before working on bare wires.

### **You could be risking your life if you do not follow basic electronic precautions.**

Comment: You can also get wireless motion sensor switches, that is, a replacement switch with a wireless remote motion sensor that transmits to the switch.

Comment: the switch is inside and the light is outside. I would like it to detect motion on the outside. I'm not able to reach the outside light. it's new construction and was not done while being built.